# Animation between two UIViewController when I do makeKeyAndVisible

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to do an animation to switch between two UIViewController that I have. But when the animation runs, the old UIViewController is white.

```
    // viewController is the new UIViewController 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 
        delay:0 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
        animations:^(void){
             [viewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -460)];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
             if (finished){
                //
             }
        }
    ];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:viewController];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have an object which always has the UIViewController:

```
@interface ManagerViews : NSObject {

    UIViewController *oneController;
    UIViewController *twoController;
    ...
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *oneController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *twoController;
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the old UIViewController to "nil" or (my Objective-C expertise is a little rusty) reset?

Comment: i meant release, not reset. sorry

Comment: No, I don't do nothing with old UIViewController

Comment: you might find this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412282/how-to-delete-uiviewcontroller-corectly) interesting